# Printing Zebra Labels using Perl CGI

Tags: perl, cgi, zebra-printers

I am having issues printing Zebra labels from a Perl CGI, where it works on one server but not another. Also, if I run the program from the command line it works on either server. The servers are IIS 7 (don't laugh it's what I'm stuck using).

Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use Socket;
use CGI qw(:cgi-lib);
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
my %formdata = Vars;

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

# to test running from the command line, hardcode the paramters normally passed from the web interface
# comment these out when running CGI
$formdata{printer} = "zebraprinter.mycompany.com";
$formdata{serials} = "TR16170003|Gerry's Product TR|This is a generic product where all serial numbers start with the letters TR|T~";

# initialize server and port
my $port = 9100;       
# create the socket, connect to the port
socket(SOCKET,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,(getprotobyname('tcp'))[2]) or myExit("Can't create a socket $!\n");    
connect( SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($formdata{printer}))) or myExit("Can't connect to port $port! \n");

foreach my $serial(split("~", $formdata{serials}))
{
    my @ar = split(/\|/, $serial);
    my $line;
    if ($formdata{printer} =~ /label2/) # small labels
    {
        $line = "^XA^PRA,A,A^LH5,5^FO10,10^BCN,50,N,N,N,D^FD$ar[0]^FS";
        $line .= "^FO300,10^AD,15,12^FDSerial Number:^FS";
        $line .= "^FO300,30^AD,15,12^FD$ar[0]^FS^XZ";
    }
    else # large labels
    {
        $line = "^XA^PRA,A,A^LH20,20";
        $line .= "^FO20,40^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Serial Number: $ar[0]^FS";
        $line .= "^FO20,120^FWN^AT,60,10^FD $ar[1]^FS";

        # need to hard break and limit long lines
        if (length($ar[2]) > 60)
        {
            my $part = substr($ar[2],0,60);
            $line .= "^FO20,200^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Description: $part^FS";
            $part = substr($ar[2],61,74);
            $line .= "^FO20,260^FWN^AT,60,10^FD$part^FS";
            $line .= "^FO50,340^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD$ar[0]^FS";
        }
        else
        {
            $line .= "^FO20,200^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Description: $ar[2]^FS";
            $line .= "^FO50,280^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD$ar[0]^FS";
        }
        $line .= "^XZ";
        # example formatted label
        #$line = qq~^XA^PRA,A,A^LH20,20^FO20,40^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Serial Number: $ar[0]^FS^FO20,120^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Product: $ar[1]^FS^FO20,200^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Description: $ar[2]^FS^FO50,280^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD$ar[0]^FS^XZ~;
    }
    print SOCKET $line;
}    
close SOCKET;
myExit("Labels Printed.");

sub myExit
{
    my $msg = shift;
    print "<script>alert('$msg')</script>";
    exit;
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with opening sockets in a CGI but I don't have a whole lot of experience with that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly what unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Is anything being written to the web server error log? Are you sure that both of the servers have access to the printers?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went in after the weekend to try and gather more information and it works now. The only thing that happened over the weekend is that they reboot the servers but it makes no sense to me why that would fix this issue. I had suspected some sort of firewall type issue but can't confirm that. I've put in a lot more debugging information now and will report back if it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that our Zebra printer is sending a response after printing labels and waiting to verify it was delivered, which locked it up. The solution that is working so far is to get the response but also set a short timeout on the socket just in case. Also went up the food chain and used IO::Socket instead of the old Socket library:

```
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
use CGI qw(:cgi-lib);
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
my %formdata = Vars;

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

# to test running from the command line, hardcode the paramters normally passed from the web interface
# comment these out when running CGI
$formdata{printer} = "zebralabel1.mycompany.com";
$formdata{serials} = "TR16170003|Gerry's Product TR|This is a generic product where all serial numbers start with the letters TR|T~";

# create the socket, connect to the port
my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                Proto   => 'tcp',
                PeerAddr=> "$formdata{printer}",
                PeerPort=> "9100",
                ReuseAddr=> 0,
                Timeout  => 2,
                ) or myExit("Cannot connect to printer: $!");
$remote->autoflush(1);  # Send immediately

my ($serial, $product, $desc) = split(/\|/, $formdata{serials});
# example formatted label
my $line = qq~^XA^PRA,A,A^LH20,20^FO20,40^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Serial Number: $serial^FS^FO20,120^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Product: $product^FS^FO20,200^FWN^AT,60,10^FD Description: $desc^FS^FO50,280^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD$serial^FS^XZ~;

print $remote $line;
my $dontCare = <remote>;

close $remote;
myExit("Labels Printed.");

sub myExit
{
    my $msg = shift;
    print "<script>alert('$msg')</script>";
    exit;
}
```